# location of userControls on different screens

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

What is the best way to solve this problem:

I create dynamically in my window application tabs with background image and according to image I put customUserControls. Then I save all tabs, images and userControls to database. So in my database I saved position of the userControls. But if I will open this application with saved information on screen with different resolution, then all userControls will be shown with wrong positions. I was thinking to solve this issue by saving screen resolution to database and before creation of userControls from database check current resolution with resolution from database, and if they differ, recalculate position of userControl. 
Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is filed under WPF. Why would you not layout the controls using the WPF layout grid, stack panels, and such to make use of the power of WPF?

Using the layout controls allows you to have a form that will appear properly no matter how it is re-sized or what resolution screen your application runs on.